# Where is the documentation for writing an OS X accessibility client?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Apple has [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/AboutOSXAccessibility/AboutOSXAccessibility.html) for adding accessibility information to one's own app. This allows accessibility clients to control that app. However, I can find no information writing one's own accessibility client. I'd like to control other apps through their UI from an OS X application (not via AppleScript, ScriptingBridge, or a third part framework, BTW). I'd like to write a real accessibility client--where is the documentation for doing this?

This is what I've found so far:

- [Manually sending Quartz events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/). This is a much lower level than the new Accessibility tools that come with OS X Yosemite.
- [An old Carbon framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityCarbonRef/index.html). This doesn't work on 64-bit Macs. Pretty-much useless today.
- [This header file](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXUIElement_header_reference/index.html) has some information about controlling an application. It's just a header file--no guide, no examples. I also can't see how to get from this structure to the methods in the protocol described in [1](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/AboutOSXAccessibility/AboutOSXAccessibility.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The header files are pretty much it, there is an example called [UI Element Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html)

Opening the actual header file in the SDK might be helpful as there are a lot of comments and documentation which might not be available on the website